# What is the inverse of $A^{-1}+B^{-1}+C^{-1}$ for square matrices $A,B,C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm a beginner in Liner Algebra and lately I encountered the following question:

> If $A,B,A+B$ are all nonsingular matrices of order $n$, prove that $A^{-1}+B^{-1}$ is also nonsingular.

The answer is obvious if one can notice that $A(A+B)^{-1}B(A^{-1}+B^{-1})=I_n$. The fun part is that if we see matrices as numbers, the equation simply means $$\frac{AB}{A+B}\left(\frac{1}{A}+\frac{1}{B}\right)=1.$$ Therefore, I was wondering if there is a way to define something like "matrix fraction" while solving the problem that matrices being not commutative. I started looking for the inverse of $A^{-1}+B^{-1}+C^{-1}$ but seemed to fail. So now what I really want to know is that does this generalization exist? If the answer is yes, is it necessary?

Comment: You need conditions on $A,B,C$, otherwise the sum need not be invertible at all. And you may want to apply your result on $(A^{-1}+B^{-1})+C^{-1}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  Yes, you are right. Actually I think it's part of the generalization because if you want to get $1/x$, you must ensure $x\neq 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Such a generalization *does* exist, and you're already 2/3rds of the way there with your case for two matrices. You've shown that if $A$, $B$, and $A+B$ are invertible, then so is $A^{-1} + B^{-1}$.

Now considering three matrices $A$, $B$, and $C$: if $A$, $B$, and $A+B$ are all invertible then we know $A^{-1} + B^{-1}$ is invertible. So let $D^{-1} = A^{-1} + B^{-1}$, i.e. $D = A(A+B)^{-1}B$.

By the first statement again, if $C$ and $C + D$ are invertible then so is $D^{-1} + C^{-1} = A^{-1} + B^{-1} + C^{-1}$.

In sum, if $A$, $B$, $C$, $A+B$, and $A(A+B)^{-1}B + C$ are all invertible, then so is $A^{-1} + B^{-1} + C^{-1}$. See if you can do better and write down the formula for the inverse of $A^{-1} + B^{-1} + C^{-1}$ by substituting $C$ and $D$ into your first formula in place of $A$ and $B$.